# Proximal point, Moreau envelope, grad. of Moreau env. when domain is constrained / subset of $\mathbb{R}^d$

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, non-smooth-analysis, non-smooth-optimization

Let $f:\mathcal{K}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a convex function, with $\mathcal{K}\subset \mathbb{R}^d$ a convex set, *the domain of $f$  is constrained/a strict subset of   $\mathbb{R}^d$*.

How do we define the following for the case that $\mathcal{K}\subset \mathbb{R}^d$ (I include their "unconstrained" version):

- The [Moreau envelope](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Moreau_envelope_function) of $f$, $f_{\lambda}(x) = \mathrm{min}_{x'} \{ f(x') + \frac{1}{2\lambda}\|x' - x \|^2 \}$,
- The proximal point of $x$ with respect to $\lambda f$, $\mathrm{prox}_{\lambda f} :=\mathrm{argmin}_{x'} \{ f(x') + \frac{1}{2\lambda}\|x' - x \|^2 \}$
- The gradient of the Moreau envelope, $\nabla f_\lambda$.

One can notice that the $\mathrm{min}$ operator is over the whole $\mathbb{R}^d$.

(see this [book](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/papers/pdf/prox_algs.pdf) for the unconstrained case $\mathcal{K} = \mathbb{R}^d$)

Does it still hold that:
$ \nabla f_{\lambda}(x) = (x - \mathrm{prox}_{\lambda f}(x))$?

Comment: [Moreau envelope](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Moreau_envelope_function). Can you finish ? Or at least put the question into some context so that we know where the problems exactly are. No one wants to google those answers for you.

Comment: You can extend $f$ to be defined on all of $\mathbb R^d$ by declaring that $f(x) = \infty$ if $x \notin \mathcal K$. The new function $f$ is still convex.

Comment: The “effective domain” of a function $f: \mathbb R^d \to \mathbb R \cup \{\infty \}$ is defined to be $\{ x \in \mathbb R^d \mid f(x) < \infty \}$. Even if the effective domain of  a closed convex function $f$ is a strict subset of $\mathbb R^d$, the Moreau envelope of $f$ turns out to be a differentiable function on $\mathbb R^d$.

Comment: By the way, I think Boyd and Vandenberghe tend to use the term “domain” for what I am calling the “effective domain”. I find that to be a bit confusing, because it conflicts with the usual definition of the term “domain”.

Comment: What if $f$ is $L$-Lipschitz continuous and we want to retain this property?